# migrate from jQuery to Zepto

Tags: javascript, jquery, zepto

im using many plugins in jQuery...

im trying to migrate to Zepto and i have this problem

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return A.init(a,b)} has no method 'data'
```

in console

```
$.data
undefined
```

in my html(im using jade compiler)

```
script(src="/javascripts/assets/zepto/zepto.min.js")
script(src="/javascripts/assets/zepto/data.js")
script
    Zepto.browser = {webkit: true}
    window.jQuery = Zepto
```

and im still gettin this

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return A.init(a,b)} has no method 'data' 
$.data
undefined
```

this is the data.js [data.js](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/blob/master/src/data.js) and this is github [Zepto](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto)

anybody can explain me what's wrong???

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a [`jQuery.data` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/), which Zepto doesn't seem to have. This should work as an implementation:

```
$.data = function(elem, key, value){
    return $(elem).data(key, value);
}
```

Comment: have you seen the data.js implementation that i posted?

Comment: @andrescabana86: Yes. `$.data` is different from `$.fn.data`.